# Pointers looking like function pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

As I starting to learn C++, this question may be stupid but I do not understand some strange pointers.

```
void (*p1(int*))(float*);
int* (*(*p2)(double(*fp1)(char), int*))(float *);
int* (*(*p3)(double(*)(char), int*))(double*);
```

I think `p2` and `p3` are function pointers pointing to a function that returns a pointer to int but I am totally lost about the rest.
Also I don't understand p1 at all.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not somewhere you go when starting to learn the language

Comment: I am in the chapter about advanced pointers but I do not understand everything so I am asking here.

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=int%2A+%28%2A%28%2Ap3%29%28double%28%2A%29%28char%29%2C+int%2A%29%29%28double%2A%29%3B

Comment: This is horrible code. Calling it "advanced pointers" does not change that. Any sane programmer will use typedefs to make it clear what's what. Don't bother with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `p1(int*)` we know that `p1` is a function taking argument `int*`.  The return type of the function is the rest of the declaration once we delete the part we already analyzed, `void (*)(float*)` (i.e. pointer to function taking `float *` and returning `void`.

`p2` and `p3` have the same form, just p2 gives  a name to the function parameter. So I will only address one of them, p3.

Because of `(*p3)(double(*)(char), int *)` we know that `(*p3)` is a function taking arguments `double(*)(char)` and `int *`.  The return type of the function is the rest of the declaration without the part we already analyzed, i.e. `int*(*)(double *)`.  Since `(*p3)` has that function type, then `p3`'s type is: pointer to that function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand this a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

`p1` is a function that returns a pointer to a function. You are correct about `p2`. It is a pointer to a function that takes two arguments - a pointer to a function and a pointer to an int - and returns a pointer to a function. `p3` is the same.